# No overload for method 'LogException' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#

**Problem:** No overload for method 'LogException' takes 2 arguments.

**Description:** I have a method which should be able to take additional info optionally, so I added an optional parameter / argument (*option 1*). That didn't work, so I tried making 2 methods (*option 2*). Now I'm pretty sure it isn't a coding error, but rather something with Visual Studio (2010). I've tried cleaning, rebuilding and building (after deleting bin folder), but the error "No overload..." always stops the build process.

**Call**

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    ServerLog.Instance.LogException(e, (object)info);
}
```

**Implementation option 1**

```
public void LogException(Exception e, object info=null) { ... }
```

**Implementation option 2**

```
public void LogException(Exception e) { LogException(e, null); }
public void LogException(Exception e, object info) { ... }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a 'project' type reference and not a 'bin' type reference, to ensure it updates as you change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paddy was right, wrong reference type. Thanks for your help, and feel free to add your comment as an answer (for the reputation).